# How do I track down the source definition of a custom hook event in a Mediawiki extension?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Here's an example:

https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/EPFM/browse/master/?grep=BeforeFreeTextSubst

A Mediawiki extension where Hooks::run( 'PageForms::BeforeFreeTextSubst', ...) gets invoked but there's no other record or trace of where it's defined. If there was some mapping of strings/names to functions it would be registered somewhere else, and if it was a function name it should show up somewhere else.

I'm seeing this with a few other function hook events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any "source definition" other than where the hook is run from. That is where the hook is defined; it may or may not actually be hooked *onto* anywhere. All the hook definition is is a name and a set of parameters that are passed to hook callbacks.

To help find out where the hook is actually used, you can use the (new) codesearch tool:

https://codesearch.wmflabs.org/extensions/?q=BeforeFreeTextSubst

(It looks like this one is not used by any extension that is in Wikimedia source control.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to find the functions that get called when the hook is run? The situation is a bit chaotic there. There are two mechanisms for defining hooks:

- the [`$wgHooks`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHooks) global (this is the normal way of registering hooks);
- and the `Hooks::register` method (sometimes used for registering hooks dynamically).

`$wgHooks` is normally set via the `extension.json` file, but can be set dynamically, too.

The quickest way to find out what hooks are registered is to run `maintenance/shell.php` and type in `$wgHooks`. This will miss hooks registered via the other method, and hooks which are conditionally registered (e.g. only for API calls), but it still works 99% of the time. Otherwise, you'll have to grep for it, as Sam said.